# Can DNA base pairs go through each other?

Tags: dna, theoretical-biology

Consider the simplified version of the motion one DNA base pair held together by a hydrogen bond:

1. Use u and v to denote the displacements of the bases from their equilibrium position along the direction of the hydrogen bond that connects them,
2. Define y = u-v to measure the stretching distance between the bases in a pair of bases. 
   So, y = 0. u=v. No stretching. When y > 0. Stretching. When y < 0. Compression. u

I would like to say, that physically, it is not possible for u to go through v or vice versa. Meaning that the stretching distance measured by y has a lower bound. In other words and my question, does it make physical sense for two base pairs to go through each other?

Comment: What do you mean by going through? Is there any terminology for this?

Comment: I do not have any terminology for this. I am trying to visualize what the model implies. I am assuming that if that we have 1 dimensional motion (1 degree of freedom) and if I, say, fix u and let v move towards u (compression), then eventually it will have to go through u if the motion of both bases is along the hydrogen bond.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is Physics.

Comment: Covalent chemical bonds between atoms like C-N, C=N, C-C, C=C etc are actually maintained by electron orbits. It is hard to disturb these orbits. When they are disturbed, the bonds would break, which means some chemical reaction occurs. Then you get different chemicals--they are not u and v anymore. That is what I think. This seems more chemical thing rather than biology.

Comment: @243 I think OP is describing a situation where you have 2 bases in a plane, and push 1 towards the other, still in the plane. As the bases moved closer the atoms would begin to repel. We can think of it in terms of [Leonard-Jones Potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential), where the repulsive force is inversely proportional to the distance to the 12th power. This means that the repulsion gets really high really fast. Since the bases are magically locked in the plane, you'd probably push them close together and stop. In reality, one would pop above or to side of other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base pair you are describing is only stable if each base is part of a macromolecular polymer, a polynucleotide. Specifically the DNA strands need to be oriented in an anti parallel alignment, and there will be a chain, or string, of base pairs (imagine the rungs of a ladder).
Remember, individual hydrogen, or H-bonds, are one of the weakest molecular interactions that we can detect. So the scenario you propose, where one single base forms a Watson-Crick base pair with its complementary base, free in solution, is so unstable as to be undetectable.

Once the base pairs are formed in a DNA double helix (think of a flexible ladder where one end is fixed and the other end has been twisted through several clockwise revolutions) then there are many other energetic contributions that stabilize the base pairs. For example, the electrostatic repulsion of the anionic phosphates in the sugar-phosphate backbone drives the two strands apart.  The hydrophobic stacking interactions of the pi bonds of adjacent bases also makes a major contribution to the stability of the helix, and permits the H-bonds to be more stable in this context.

Finally, the fact that base pairs are only stable in polynucleotides means that if you melt a single base pair, the sugar phosphate backbones will topologically prevent any other melted base pair from "passing through" the first one.